# Search for Specific Text in a Multi-Select

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, multi-select, contains

I have a multi-select that lists bandwidths. Some are in Mbps, and some are in Gbps. I need to know if any of the selected options is over 1 Gbps, so I'd like to search the multi-select for the text 'Gbps'. Right now I have a checkbox formula that looks something like this:

```
INCLUDES(Bandwidth_s__c, "2 Gbps") ||
INCLUDES(Bandwidth_s__c, "5 Gbps") ||
INCLUDES(Bandwidth_s__c, "10 Gbps") ||
INCLUDES(Bandwidth_s__c, "100 Gbps")
```

This is problematic because as Sales makes new sales for all manner of custom bandwidths, items get added to this picklist. I'd like to be able to future-proof this, mainly because it's hard to create a process that guarantees that this formula is updated when a value is added to the picklist.

Does anyone have any ideas (including record triggered flows or apex triggers) for how I can populate a checkbox for this without having to specify individual values?

*Edit: Anything less complex than an Apex Trigger?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Sure, this is easy to do in an Apex trigger by parsing the string, or you could create a separate field for value ("2") and unit ("Gbps") and use those in your formula field

Comment: can Sales create entries like `1500 Mbps` ? if  so, I'd do apex. Note that in flow, you can escape to UnofficialSf.com flow action to return a MSP as a text collection that you could then loop through (not pretty, but doable) to populate a _non-formula_ checkbox

Comment: Create two Field instead of one speed & metric and then concatenate it in a third field in that case your formula will be easy